# Comparing key, value pairs equivalent in R

Tags: python, r

I'm going from Python to R and I wanted to compare two things that I would normally use a `dict` for by doing something like this:

```
dict_one = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict_two = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}

for key1, value1 in dict_one.items():
    if dict_two[key1] != value1:
        print(key1)  #prints c
```

Is there anything similar R? I've made two named lists

```
list_one <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
list_two <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 4)
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't output what I was looking for.

```
> list_one %in% list_two
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE #looking for TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Have you tried using environments?

Comment: It (using `%in%`) works for me. But it matches the value, NOT the key and value. `list_three <- list(a = 1, b = 2, d = 3)`, `list_one %in% list_three` yields `TRUE TRUE TRUE`

Comment: do your R lists only contains "scalar" (vector of length one) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do (this will take into consideration possible different ordering in your list):

```
> unlist(list_two[names(list_one)])!=unlist(list_one)
    a     b     c 
FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Wow, this is really, really good. Tiny change, I was looking for `==` as the comparison, not `!=`.

Comment: Glap to help, yes you can adapt with `==` of course!

Answer (score 1):

In a simple case like yours, I would not use lists, I would just use vectors `c()`function in R.

```
list_one <- c(1,2,3)
list_two <- c(1,2,4)
list_one==list_two
```

Which gives `[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE` as you whished.

I hope I've helped you.

Comment: But it's important for me to know which didn't match.... This is a very simplified example